# Python script keeps getting killed

Tags: ubuntu, vps, python, digital-ocean

I run a python script on VPS and I have problem that script keeps getting killed.

I had this problem already with 2GB RAM server config, then I upgraded to 4 GB and it seemed to fix the problem (at least for 2-3 days - but now happening again) but if I check the memory graphs I see the server load is max 20% of memory and still it is killed.

The output of cmd "grep Killed /var/log/syslog" is the following:

```
May  8 07:42:04 ubuntu kernel: [307104.437195] Out of memory: Killed process 28187 (python3) total-vm:4503732kB, anon-rss:2885740kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:0 pgtables:6780kB oom_score_adj:0
May  8 07:50:46 ubuntu kernel: [307627.171853] Out of memory: Killed process 28387 (python3) total-vm:4569972kB, anon-rss:2887600kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:0 pgtables:6772kB oom_score_adj:0
May  8 07:55:18 ubuntu kernel: [  213.775489] Out of memory: Killed process 1944 (python3) total-vm:4927788kB, anon-rss:3209304kB, file-rss:2460kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:0 pgtables:7216kB oom_score_adj:0
May  8 08:01:31 ubuntu kernel: [  586.779207] Out of memory: Killed process 2111 (python3) total-vm:4593116kB, anon-rss:3205464kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:0 pgtables:7156kB oom_score_adj:0
```

Is there anything i can do?

Here is the mem load screenshot. (Yes there are rwo spike 98% MEM but that was only 2 attempts of like 4 when running the scripts. Meaning in other cases it even killed with 20% mem load)

[image]

Btw i suppose the times on the image are same as in the log above but you have to do -2h substraction.

Comment: Did you write the Python script yourself? Is it supposed to be a memory intensive job? If not, it may have bugs. It would then also be more of a programming question than a server admin question (so, for Stack Overflow)

Comment: yes i wrote the script, i ran it many days with 2 gb ram then some days with 4 gb ram

Comment: it is a server question, it keeps getting killed with 20% CPU

Comment: Can you show htop sorted by memory when you're running it (for a while)?

Comment: @Halfgaar good idea thanks. i now noticed that if i run the python script it makes multiple like 4 processes with the "python3 scriptname" is that normal? and it really consumed all memory

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for tips guys I've figured out what was the problem. I read the websites (multi threaded) like 32 threads at once even. I lowered the count of threads to 1 to read one websites after each other (serially) and I noticed there was some website doing the infinitive output causing the memory crash.

Specifically it was btw this website [www.dead-episode.de](http://www.dead-episode.de) :D which is a good name for mem crashing website.